# ignore list and ignore-on-commit on TFS

Tags: svn, tfs, commit

On Subversion/TortouseSVN we have 2 features:

1. right click a file > Unversion and add to ignore list: this one removes a folder/file from repository and it's never commited
2. Check for modifications > right click a file > Move to change list > ignore-on-commit: this one keeps the file on repository, but its changes are ignored when commiting

I'd like these features on MS TFS. Any idea where it is on Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a Local Workspace (in TFS/Visual Studio 2012 or better) then you have these options. You have the option to check in a `.tfignore` file and it can be managed through the Include/Exclude pending changes elements on the pending changes window.

See also:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#tfignore

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna take a look on this tfignore. Where should I place it? Can I create it on WinExplorer and add it as existing to VisualStudio, then I just need to commit it? And should I create 1 for each project or for each solution?

Comment: When using the context menu in Visual Studio, the file is auto created and added. If you're doing it manually, then I believe the workspace root is the right place to put it.